# Unix style pipe with AWS lambdas?

Tags: pipe, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to orchestrate Amazon lambda functions similar to unix pipes, but with every function handing its original payload (and results) on to the next:

```
charge_customer | send_log | email_customer
```

`charge_customer` is invoked via the API Gateway.

I've thought about achieving this with SNS: Do a

```
client_fetch('POST', 'url/to/first_func', payload_including_next_funcs)
```

and then putting `first_func`s result on to SNS.

But it doesn't seem possible without the first lambda waiting for all others to complete. I could as well have a first lambda invoke all others and then return.

Is there a way to achieve such a mechanism? Or another way I can avoid having all code in a single lambda, and still achieve it with a single API Gateway roundtrip and no lambdas waiting on each other?

Comment: From the look of your function names, it seems to me that `send_log` and `email_customer` are not actions that the client making the request really cares about. In which case you could simply invoke both `send_log` and `email_customer` as "events" from inside the `charge_customer` function before returning from it.

Comment: you can simply invoke another functionB from within functionA asynchronously

Comment: Thanks both. @idbehold, I was hoping to avoid doubling the lambda cost using some amazon internal mechanism, but perhaps that's not possible.

Comment: @hnvasa, I'll check this out, maybe a solution - with the limitation it seems that I can't return a final done/success/failure to the client then.

Comment: If you simply want to invoke a lambda function without waiting for a response you can use the "Event" Invocation type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) for this.